# get check box value dynamically using dynamic check box name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

javascript.js

```
function getbyname(url, emId, obj){
   alert(emId)
    var checked = $('input[name="rsvp_role"+emId+"[]"]:checked').val();//error in this line not getting the value of name
    alert(checked)
   """"""""""""""""""
   other code comes here
   """""""""""""""""""
```

I want to get the value of checked check box using name.I alerted the emId variable in alert i am getting the correct id ,but if i concatenate and pass that emId in rsvpApproval function i am not getting the  value of that name.I alert i am getting undefined as value.

Is it possible to get the value of checkbox from dynamic name of check box.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string concatenation is not proper, the string is delimited using `'` but you are trying to use `+` with the delimiter `"`

```
var checked = $('input[name="rsvp_role'+emId+'[]"]:checked').val();
```

Comment: @user2681579 there is a problem again `input["name=rsvp_role113[]"]:checked"` should be `input[name="rsvp_role113[]"]:checked"` - did you use the same code as I gave

Comment: Sorry i corrected afterwards and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate your `emId` properly here using `'`:

```
var checked = $('input[name="rsvp_role' + emId + '[]"]:checked').val();
```

instead of

```
var checked = $('input[name="rsvp_role"+emId+"[]"]:checked').val();
```